# ninjaforms plugin write on file on submission

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I am not a web developer and I am trying to figure out how to use ninjaforms plugin for wordpress.

What I want to achieve is to execute a php script after submission of the form.
I have followed the instructions on how to create a Custom Action Form at this link

http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/custom-form-action/.

In my custom action if I call some APIs it works correctly, but if I insert the following code in my function

```
 $fp = fopen('php.log', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, 'Cats chase');
 fwrite($fp, 'mice');
 fclose($fp);
```

nothing is written into the file. Can you suggest how to debug it? or do you have any idea why these instructions are not executed?

in the error logs there is no error and it seems that php is executing correctly.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up action correctly (given that api calls succeed) it's likely that your file is also created though likely not where you expect it to be, so instead of 'php.log' do something like ABSPATH . 'php.log'. This will create file in your WordPress root directory (same directory as your wp-config.php).

`$fp = fopen(ABSPATH . 'php.log', 'w');`